# How do you $watch input in ng-repeat separately and append result to specific row in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexing, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-watch

I have two input fields b_price and s_price inside ng-repeat. I need to watch changes in these two models and append estimated. My code snippet:
html

```
<body ng-app="testthis" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <table>
    <tr  ng-repeat="list in testList.lists track by $index">

                <td>{{list.symbol}}</td>
                <td>{{list.todays_rate}}</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="testList.b_price"></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="testList.s_price"></td>
                <td>{{estimated}}</td>

            </tr>
                    </table>
        </body>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('testthis', []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.testList ={};
    $scope.testList.lists = [{id: 1,symbol: "assas", total: 123},
                                {id: 2,symbol: "as", total: 103}];



 for (var i=0; i<$scope.testList.lists.length; i++){

  $scope.estimated =0;
  $scope.$watch('testList.b_price + testList.s_price', function() {
    console.log('watch');
    if ($scope.testList.b_price){
      console.log('as');
      $scope.testList.s_price = "";
      $scope.estimated = 100 - $scope.testList.b_price;
    }else if ($scope.testList.s_price){
      $scope.testList.b_price = "";
      $scope.estimated = $scope.testList.s_price - 100;
    } 
  });
 }

});
```

When I input value in first row's input tag i get it repeated in  second row's input. This can be fixed using ng-model="testList.b_price[$index]". But I am unable to watch this value i.e $scope.testList.b_price[0], $scope.testList.b_price[i] gives error inside $watch. 
One more issue , I am unable to append estimated as estimated[0], estimated[2].Fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/sanj9090/b07jkstj/](https://jsfiddle.net/sanj9090/b07jkstj/)